# Overriding (==) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I have the following algebraic data types:

```
data Exp
  = Con Int
  | Var String
  | Op Opkind Exp Exp
  | Input
  deriving (Show,Eq)

data Opkind
  = Plus | Minus | Mult | Div | More | Equal
  deriving (Show,Eq)
```

That represent expressions in a simple toy language.

However, because I derive Eq, `Op Plus (Var "a") (Var "b)` is not considered equal to `Op Plus (Var "b") (Var "a")` even though I would like to treat `a+b` as an equal expression to `b+a`.

How do I change `(==)` for just those instances, without having to specify the behaviour of `(==)` for all the other instances?

Comment: By "instances" you mean "cases" or "variants" (remember that "instances" has a specific meaning in Haskell wrt. typeclasses).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve this by making Exp an instance of Eq instead of deriving Eq:

```
instance Eq Exp where
    (Con a) == (Con b) = a == b
    (Var a) == (Var b) = a == b
    (Op Plus a b) == (Op Plus c d) = (a == c && b == d) || (a == d && c == b)
    Input == Input = True
    _ == _ = False
```

This would compare Op Plus in the way wanted, but is still missing the other cases for Op.

**Edit:**

The easiest way to implement special cases for (==) on Op without losing the derive on Exp, that comes to my mind would be something like this:

```
data Exp
  = Con Int
  | Var String
  | EOp Op
  | Input
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Op = Op Opkind Exp Exp deriving (Show)
instance Eq Op where
    (Op Plus e1 e2) == (Op Plus e3 e4) = (e1 == e3 && e2 == e4) || ( e1 == e4 && e2 == e3)
    (Op kind1 e1 e2) == (Op kind2 e3 e4) = and [kind1 == kind2, e1 == e3, e2 == e4]
```

Comment: The key phrase was "without having to specify the behaviour of (==) for other instances". I had hoped that the `OverlappingInstances` pragma would do the trick but I can't seem to wrangle it.

Comment: @Dan: `OverlappingInstances` lets you write multiple `instance` declarations that could potentially match the same type: think `instance Foo (f [a])` and `instance Foo (Maybe [a])` which overlap for types like `Maybe [Int]`. The question here is about only a single instance for a single data type.

Comment: @camccan that makes sense. I wish we had something like `UseNewestInstance` or perhaps `DerivePartialInstances`

Comment: @Dan And the horrible part comes when you have `instance Foo (f [Int])` and `instance Foo (Maybe [a])`. What do you do for `Maybe [Int]`?

Answer (score 10):

If you want custom behavior for `Op`, but regular behavior for all other variants of your datatype, you'll need to break out `Op` into its own type.

For example:

```
data Exp
  = Con Int
  | Var String
  | Input
  | PrimOp Op
  deriving (Show,Eq)

data Op = Op Opkind Exp Exp
  deriving Show

data Opkind
  = Plus | Minus | Mult | Div | More | Equal
  deriving (Show,Eq) 

-- equality on (symbolic) functions, perhaps?
instance Eq Op where
  (Op a _ _) == (Op b _ _) = a == b
```

Let's you define all expressions structurally equal, except for applications of functions to arguments, which are equal by name only (which may or may not be useful).

Comment: +1. While your particular Eq instance isn't necessarily suited to the OP's needs, the technique of splitting it into its own datatype certainly is.